# RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH blocked when a tap occurs

Tags: java, android, google-glass, android-logcat, google-gdk

In my main activity I launch a new Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "What would you like to find?\n For example \"Open heart surgery\"");
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
```

Then I retrieve the keywords that were spoken here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ApiDemoActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("keyword", spokenText);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now all this works just fine, but I noticed a problem. During the RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH.. if I tap the google glass (in any way on the D-pad), it'll bug out the voice recognition. Meaning that it refuses to detect any sound. What could be causing this problem?

**Logcat Update**

I'm getting two main errors during the SPEECH_REQUEST when I tap the Dpad:

```
12-08 10:12:58.687: E/SpeechRecognizer(940): not connected to the recognition service

12-08 10:12:58.695: E/GlassRecognitionService[41e733b8](940): VoiceService disconnected.
```

**Logcat:**

```
12-03 09:45:06.513: E/SpeechRecognizer(847): not connected to the recognition service
12-03 09:45:06.513: I/BroadcastingVoiceInputCallback[425b67c8](847): Unregistered GlassRecognitionService
12-03 09:45:06.513: E/GlassRecognitionService[42b01bf0](847): VoiceService disconnected.
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/RecognizerController(847): stopListening
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/RecognizerController(847): detachVoiceInputCallback
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/RecognizerFactory(847): deactivate() called on no-op recognizer, nothing to do.
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/VoiceEngine[425ecfd8](847): Setting active recognizer: VoiceConfig []
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/RecognizerFactory(847): activate() called on no-op recognizer, nothing to do.
12-03 09:45:06.521: I/RecognizerController(847): cancel
12-03 09:45:06.537: D/dalvikvm(847): threadid=47: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
12-03 09:45:06.545: D/native_audio_voice_microphone(847): *** Close native audio interface for GlassVoice. NativeAudioInterfaceWrapper_nativeClose() ***
12-03 09:45:06.552: I/ConcurrentAudioInterface[4256aec8](847): Closed audio interface.
```

**then a couple seconds later:**

```
12-03 09:45:16.295: V/GlassNotification(589): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.glass.settings.ui
12-03 09:45:16.295: V/GlassNotification(589): skipping since notification not whitelisted
12-03 09:45:19.529: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0xd9
12-03 09:45:19.529: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x17b
12-03 09:45:19.537: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x234
12-03 09:45:19.537: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x315
12-03 09:45:19.592: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 8% free 5774K/6212K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 46ms
12-03 09:45:32.279: V/GlassNotification(589): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.glass.settings.ui
12-03 09:45:32.279: V/GlassNotification(589): skipping since notification not whitelisted
12-03 09:45:43.490: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0xd9
12-03 09:45:43.498: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x17b
12-03 09:45:43.506: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x234
12-03 09:45:43.506: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x315
12-03 09:45:44.412: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0xd9
12-03 09:45:44.412: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x17b
12-03 09:45:44.420: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x234
12-03 09:45:44.420: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x315
12-03 09:45:45.638: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0xd9
12-03 09:45:45.638: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x17b
12-03 09:45:45.646: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x234
12-03 09:45:45.654: E/ming$MessageInputStream(770): bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0x41 at 0x315
12-03 09:45:48.295: V/GlassNotification(589): Received notification id: 1 packageName: com.google.glass.settings.ui
12-03 09:45:48.295: V/GlassNotification(589): skipping since notification not whitelisted
12-03 09:45:48.342: D/dalvikvm(725): GC_EXPLICIT freed 173K, 4% free 5225K/5440K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 38ms
12-03 09:45:55.217: V/AlarmManager(506): triggered: flg=0x4 cmp=com.google.glass.logging/.WatchdogService
```

**Update:**

I noticed that once I bug the `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` , a couple swipe downs in a row will finally be detected and I return either to a new RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH or it just leaves the app completely. I'll post more information about this in the coming days.

Comment: It is working fine in my test app. When I tap on the D-pad while in the activity, I simply get a DISALLOWED sound effect. Were there any errors printed to logcat?

Comment: @user2954771 I added the logcat.

Comment: Very weird. Maybe you should just override the tap event through a GestureDetector?

Comment: Have you tried isolating this code in a new project? Same behavior?

Comment: @user2954771 that's a good idea. I'll try it tomorrow. AlexK I'll try that as well.

Comment: @user2954771 , I followed your idea still causing the same problem.

Comment: Interesting... Could you try reinstalling your GDK preview in the SDK Manager?

Answer (score 2):

If you're still having your problem, try this:

At the very top, declare a private `GestureDetector`:

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
```

Then, in the `onCreate()` method, call a method that creates the `GestureDetector` (there is no reason to do it this way over just creating it in the `onCreate()` method - it just looks cleaner this way and is more organized):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    gestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);
}
```

The `createGestureDetector()` method looks like this:

```
private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetectorTemp = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
                        //we are creating our gesture detector here
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {  //onTap
            return true; //<---this is the key
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false; //this is the wrong kind of scroll
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) { 
            return false;
        }
    });

    return gestureDetectorTemp;
}

@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector != null) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You have to make sure to include the `onGenericMotionEvent()` method at the end there. That is what makes sure that your `GestureDetector` is notified every time a motion event occurs.

The thing that I added is very minute, but very important - by changing the return value to `true` on the `onSingleTapUp()` method, you are telling Glass that the event was handled correctly (which in this case, is just doing nothing).

You can read more about `GestureDetector`s [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector).

Comment: Tried it out and unfortunately it didn't work. It is logical since I'm trying to apply the GestureDetector directly to the activity and not to the new activity (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH). Is it even possible to attach the gesturedetector to that predefined activity?

Comment: @Grimbode Ahhh. Of course. I'm afraid not. Maybe there's a way, but I don't know it. Sorry :(